# Rubymine 8: How to turn off Database Detector

Tags: rubymine, rubymine-7

How do I turn off the Database Detector in RubyMine 8?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable a notification popup for Database Detector in File | Settings | Appearance & Behavior | Notifications.